# Batch repack of mkv files

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, command-line

Can anyone tell me how to batch repack a bunch of mkv files to mp4 keeping the same file names using the Mac command line.

Comment: What does "batch repack" mean to you? mkv and mp4 are just containers so is there to be no transcription of the video/audio or are you looking for something like a command line interface to handbreak to re-encode them differently? (basically it's hard to tell which of the two tasks you need help with initially - conversion or scripting)

Comment: Repack means to me changing the container from mkv to mp4 and not re encoding. Its the scripting I require help with.

Answer (score 5):

For ffmpeg use the following command.

```
for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy "${i/${i##*.}/mp4}"; done
```

This should create copies of all your MKV videos, converting the containers to MP4 format but not re-encoding the video and audio data within them and keeping the same filename but changing the extension from mkv to mp4.

Answer (score 3):

- Get [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) and its [command line tools](https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php)
- Open Terminal, change into the folder containing the mkv's and run

  ```
  for i in *.mkv; do
      HandBrakeCLI -Z Universal -i "$1" -o "${1/${1##*.}/mp4}"
  done
  ```

Comment: Apologies, I'm using ffmpeg is the sytnax the same ?

Comment: I have no experience with `ffmpeg` but the basic for loop is definitively the same. As for the specific parameters required by `ffmpeg` a look into the man page should help here.